# How do I determine if there are two or one numbers at the start of my string?

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing

How can I determine what number (with an **arbitrary** number of digits) is at the start of a string?

Some possible strings:

```
1123|http://example.com
2|daas
```

Which should return 1123 and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
string s = "35|...";

int result = int.Parse(new string(s.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

or (if the number is always followed by a `|`) good ol' string manipulation:

```
string s = "35|...";

int result = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('|')));
```

Comment: can also use split and limit the number of splits, if he wants to do something with the other chunk

Comment: How would you remove the number after you have parsed it?

Comment: Like the use of TakeWhile, I haven't used this extention as yet.

Comment: @Liam: Exactly. Try `s.Split(new char[] {'|'}, 2)` instead. it returns an array, the first one containing your number as a string, which you can `int.Parse`, and the second one containing the rest of the string w/ the number removed

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

str = "35|http:\/\/v10.lscache3.c.youtube.com\/videoplayback...";

Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,2}");
Match m = r.Match(str);    
if(m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Matched: " + m.Value);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No match");
}
```

will capture 1-2 digits at the beginning of the string.

Comment: can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]` and the outter `()` s aren't necessary methinks

Comment: or [:digit:] should work too...parenthesis are needed for capture group

Comment: ...and you can use m.Success() if you expect there may be lines without numbers

Comment: @burkestar in this case there's no need for the capture group. Mark is right that they can be omitted. Keeping them doesn't hurt, but by using `m.Value` you're actually not referencing the capture group. To do so you would use `m.Groups[1].Value`. Since this regex starts at the beginning of the string and isn't matching anything but digits you can omit the `()` and use `m.Value`.

Comment: @Les Good point, but it's a property, so just `m.Success`: `if (m.Success) { // do something } else { // no match }`

Comment: -1. abuse of regex when it's not really the best way to do it

Comment: regex is efficient, flexible if more advanced cases need to be considered, easy to understand and works since .NET 1.1. Linq requires .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: using regex just to capture 1 or 2 digits in a well-known position (index 0) is like using a sledge hammer to kill an ant

Comment: @Lie Ryan - 1) it is the OPs choice, 2) simple requirements seldom remain simple, 3) others reading this may have similar problem but need a more flexible solution than int.Parse().

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the number is always going to be 2 digits:

```
string str = "35|http:\/\/v10.lscache3.c.youtube.com\/videoplayback?...";
int result;
if (!int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 2), out result)) {
    int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 1), out result)
}
// use the number
```

if you're not sure how long the number is, look at the .indexOf() approach by dtb. If you need something much more complex, only then consider using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two first characters and convert to int.

```
var s = "a35|...";
short result = 0;
bool isNum = Int16.TryParse(s.Substring(0, 2), out result);
```