# How do I remove a portion of my string?

Tags: c#, parsing, text-parsing

Continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809021/how-do-i-determine-if-there-are-two-or-one-numbers-at-the-start-of-my-string), I now want to remove the number once I have found it and stored it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a slight tweak to [my response to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809021/how-do-i-determine-if-there-are-two-or-one-numbers-at-the-start-of-my-string/3809040#3809040) to instead use Regex.Replace method will git 'er done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I figured it out. Just need to find the length then delete the chars
(qual is the intergers found)

```
string length = qual.ToString();
            int length2 = length.Length;
            text.Remove(0, length2);
```

Comment: You probably meant: `text = text.Remove(0, length2);` since the string operations return a new string and do not affect the current instance (strings are immutable). Another option is `text = text.Substring(length2);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code resolves the root problem:

```
string originalString = "35|http://www.google.com|123";
string[] elements = originalString.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2);
int theNumber = int.Parse(elements[0]);   // 35
string theUrl = elements[1];              // http://www.google.com|123
```